# How to install PIL to Python 3.5 on a mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I am very new to Python installations and trying to install PIL. I have a feeling they are being installed to the wrong directory. PIP seems to have been installed fine.

Pycharm says

```
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you
use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter
located at
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5'.
```

However when checking in terminal the reply is

```
Jamess-MacBook-Pro:~ JamesParsons$ pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Its also mentions a different version of Python.

How would the best way to install PIL be as Pycharm is coming up with unresolved reference still?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On your command line:

```
$ which python
```

I'm betting that this returns:

> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

This shows your 'basic' Python (which comes preinstalled on Mac) location. Now do:

```
$ which python3
```

If that shows this:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5'

Then check for a `pip3` version:

```
$ which pip3
```

If that exists and has a similar location to `python3`, then try this:

```
$ pip3 install Pillow
```

If *that* works, there is a good chance PyCharm will now pick up the correct installation.