# Can't import numpy in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

When running the following code in python 2.7:

```
import numpy
```

I get the result:

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I have however got numpy installed for python 2.7, which is seen when running the following in terminal:

```
pip install numpy
```

I get the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Working on macOS10.13.1

What am I missing? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that your default python version is also 2.7 and not 3.x. Just run python in terminal and see the version you are getting. It should be 2.7.x

Answer (score 1):

have you tried uninstalling the numpy package and re-installing it? As mentioned you may be running python 3 instead of python 2 which could cause this issue.alternatively you could install an api like anaconda which comes with numpy pre-installed this may resolve the missing module. anaconda website: https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply! I've also got Python 3.6.1 installed and it works there. I am just confused as to why numpy seems to be in the 2.7 location but does not work with 2.7. I also tried a re-install with no luck. I am trying to use PIL in Python 3.6.1, which I don't think is compatible on MacOS, which is why I want to use 2.7. Do you by any chance know how to get PIL or pillow on 3.6.1 for mac? Many thanks!

Comment: This looks like a possible duplicate, have you looked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929306/how-to-install-pil-to-python-3-5-on-a-mac